# NGINX como proxy reverso e cache de um servidor compartilhado externo rodando apache

Tags: linux, apache, cache, nginx

Estou tentando configurar uma instância brasileira na Amazon para ser proxy reverso com cache e compactação de um servidor (aceito sugestões de painéis, de preferência gratuitos, que aceitem essa configuração) nos EUA.

O objetivo é utilizar o máximo do HD brasileiro com cache do nginx e talvez usa-la como NS para diminuir a latência e tempo gasto baixando os sites.

Assim, reduzimos os custos com hospedagem sem perder em performance.

Resumindo: Eu quero fazer cache usando nginx de um servidor nos EUA que roda apache2. Todos tutoriais que encontrei estavam relacionados a rodar nginx e apache na mesma máquina e/ou funcionavam apenas para um site, sendo necessário configuração manual para cada cliente adicional.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Pessoal, essa pergunta aqui não é muito ampla, e não está tão mal explicada assim. Da sim pra manter ela aqui no SOpt.

Comment: @Yan quando a informação que vai adicionar no comentário é pertinente a pergunta, edite a pergunta e adicione nela o comentário.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz, valeu pelo toque. Corrigi.

Answer (score 2):

Basta encaminhar as requisições feitas para seu servidor rodando Nginx e dele passar para o servidor externo, da mesma forma que encaminharia para um apache local. Este é um exemplo de configuração (fica normalmente em `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` ou `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`):

```
# definição do upstream: o servidor com apache que receberá as requisições
upstream apache {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80; 
    # Onde xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx é o endereço IP público do servidor remoto
}

# definição de onde você armazenará o cache (zona)
proxy_cache_path  /var/lib/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=apachecache:180m  max_size=500m;

# limites de tempo
proxy_connect_timeout 30;
proxy_read_timeout 120;
proxy_send_timeout 120;

# condição e tempo de armazenamento do cache
proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;

# Configuração do servidor local
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # zona de cache: deve ser o mesmo nome que keys_zone
        proxy_cache apachecache;

        # Esta diretriz fará com que você possa utilizar as configurações 
        # de VirtualHost do apache 
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;

        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_buffering         off;

        # passa para o apache
        proxy_pass              http://apache;
   }
}
```

Você precisará configurar o DNS para encaminhar para o servidor do Nginx ao invés do servidor remoto com Apache. Note que há muitas outras diretrizes disponíveis para configurar o servidor. Para mais informações, consulte: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

A compactação normalmente vem habilitada no bloco `http` do arquivo `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (diretrizes gzip*).